# Jmeter FileToString Issue - Could not read open filename.txt

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to set up a maven project to run my existing script. I am passing a **data file name(data.txt)** from a **csv setup** using column **data_file_name** in input.csv file. In a **HTTP POST**, i am using below code to **POST data.txt**

**${__eval(${__FileToString(C:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/${__eval(${data_file_name})}.txt,,}**

Now, i want to **replace file path "C:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.3"**  with maven project path. I have stored my jmeter script, csv file and data files under C:/Testing/Jmeter/src/test/jmeter folder. I went ahead and updated the above code like this

**${__eval(${__FileToString(${__eval(${data_file_name})}.txt,,}**

Basically, i want to run my script thru Jenkins and do not want to use a path which points to my machine. It should point to project workspace path. I get below warning when i use updated code

**FileToString: Could not read open: data.txt**

Not sure how to update path to use project src/jmeter path. Any help would be appreciacted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to other ways of executing JMeter test i.e.

- [Command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more details on implementing above execution scenarios.

---

If you still want to use Maven you need to know that JMeter's working directory is `target/jmeter/bin` while data files (i.e. your CSV file, your `data.txt` file, etc) live under `target/jmeter/testFiles`.

So you will need to amend your function to look like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(../testFiles/${data_file_name},,)})}
```

Comment: Thanks! Function change did not work, i still get same error message. I will start checking Jmeter Ant Task setup. Thanks again!

Comment: I got it working by copying my data files under taget/jmeter/testFiles folder using antrun step in the pom file. Thanks!